# How to completely disable the English mode in Chinese pinyin input?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, ime, chinese

In the Windows Chinese pinyin input, there are two modes - English and Chinese. These can be toggled by clicking the icon in the taskbar, or by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> (default). However, I found that if I switch between windows (typing in Chinese in Word then switching to Google Chrome for example) the mode can switch automatically, which is quite annoying. If I want to type in English I would use switch keyboards (i.e. <kbd>Win + Space</kbd> ), so is it possible to completely disable the English mode from appearing?

Comment: See if in *Settings > Time & Language > Language > Keyboard*, under "Switching input methods", you don't by any chance have checked the option of "Let me set a different input method for each app window".

Comment: [See this link](https://superuser.com/a/1732342/292784) for screenshots/guidance how to find the checkbox mentioned by @harrymc . I have the same problem as OP (John) and my "Let me set a different input method for each app window" checkbox was **unchecked**. Still as I switched between Chrome and other apps (my text editor), the English and Chinese mode would toggle; English in Chrome and Chinese in my editor. I had trouble forcing Chinese mode, even the <kbd> Shift</kbd> didn't work for me -- I had to click in the taskbar. A restart might help...