# How to get separate keyboard layout for each application in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8, keyboard-layout, windows-11

I would like to have separate keyboard layout for each application in Windows.

I want it to behave the same as it did on earlier versions of Windows.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a different input method for each app window](https://superuser.com/questions/772698/how-to-set-a-different-input-method-for-each-app-window)

Answer (score 3):

There is an option which is hidden deeply in Windows:

### In short

`PC Settings / Time & Language / Language / Keyboard / "Let me use a different input method for each app window"`

### The same with screenshots

**Step 1:** Screenshot of "Time & Language / Language":
[image: Step 1: Screenshot of "Time & Language / Language"]

**Step 2:** Check the checkbox:
[image: Step 2: Check the checkbox]

Comment: This answer would be more complete if it included how to select the keyboard layout once in an app, as shown in [How to set a different input method for each app window](https://superuser.com/a/772725/272824). But then, this question is a duplicate of that one...